# what charset should be on Ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

what locale settings I should use for Ubuntu server. LANG=C ? (I heard that it's not good to have any utf8 charset as main locale settings on servers)

what I should do to have ability read in console non latin text written in unicode charset ?

I made backup from one server using tar, then i unpack it on new server... but somehow text in files (written in non latin charset) become in question marks like that: ????
But on previous server it was fine readable text.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not good to have UTF8? Why?

Comment: I suspect this is a misunderstanding of "scripts should force the locale behavior they require instead of relying on the user's locale to be what they expect".

Comment: @geekosaur what do you mean ?

Comment: What I quoted is sensible programming practice:  if you need a particular environment, make sure you have it.  "It's not good to have UTF8" sounds like the "I don't want to think, so I'll do the fast and maybe almost right sometimes" take on it, which I see a lot.  Fact is, UTF8 is especially important on servers because the more people you have using something, the more you have the potential for them to not speak exactly the same language/character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All other things being equal, and your console/terminal supporting it, set your encoding (and associated locale environment variables) to whatever you want - the system really doesn't care, and all that's usually affected is output and appearance.

My suggestion would be ***to use utf-8 as the encoding*** and set an appropriate language. This offers you the widest range of accepted character representations while maintaining backward compatibility with ASCII/LATIN1.